# make a page refresh automaticly on a .txt change

Tags: php, html, page-refresh, file-read

so I've been trying to make a page on php request that plays youtube links

I used php and used this

```
<?php
$VID = $_GET['vid'];
echo $VID;
$file = fopen("Vid.txt","w");
fwrite($file,$VID);
?>
```

to make a $_get request to grab a youtube ID and write it on a .txt file

then I made a page to read the file and use it on a embed youtube link

```
<?php
$file = fopen ("Vid.txt","r");
$id = fread($file,filesize("Vid.txt"));
fclose($file);
echo $id;
echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $id  . '?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
?>
```

what I would like to know is how could I automaticaly reload the page when the .txt changes

P.S : I have very basic knowledge about php,html and javascript

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to find a way to detect such changes. Either you poll (every minute or so) by using a cron job to fire a script or you need to setup a directory monitoring service, the details then depend on the operating system you build on.